# Css3 Animate it animating before object is in viewport

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

so I am using css3 animate it: http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit

I followed their instructions but the children animate before they are in the viewport. Is this just me or do I need a certain meta tag?

Thanks

So i was asked for my code, here it is :

```
<div class="tile one-half imageparent">
    <img src="images/iphone6.jpg" class="animated fadeInUp go"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Only putting some code here people will be able to help you :)

Comment: animate.css is doing exactly what's expected of it. It doesn't magically know WHEN to fire off the animation, it just does it when the element is loaded. If you want it responsive to the viewport then you'll need to write some js to do so or you can use something like [wowjs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) to do it.

Comment: I understand that, but the guy provides js so that way the css does occur when it arrives in the viewport.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not familiar with that one, if you have his js in there then it looks like all your missing is the `animatedParent` class on the parent `div` like he shows in like the first paragraph of his main page.

Comment: Make sure you declare `<!doctype html>` top of your HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try data-appear-top-offset attribute for it.

```
<div class="tile one-half imageparent" data-appear-top-offset='-300'>
    <img src="images/iphone6.jpg" class="animated fadeInUp go"/>
</div>
```

Also checkout other options here : http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both libraries included.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/css3-animate-it.js'></script>
```